# What do systemd "Vacuuming done, freed 0 bytes" messages mean?

Tags: linux, logs, systemd

I'm seeing messages like the following in my systemd journal:

```
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 0 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 0 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 0 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 4198400 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 4198400 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 4198400 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 4198400 bytes
systemd-journald[52]: Vacuuming done, freed 4198400 bytes
```

What do these messages mean?

Comment: It's `journald` doing implicit vacuuming (removing archived journal files). You're seeing those messages because of this [commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/289f910e16d0a962e128979b67fed5f2ef668e00). Lennart downgraded their priority to _debug_ in this latter [commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/3bb621e1e66b704c0c2dcef31c66f7c646dd47f6) so with newer `systemd` versions you should no longer see those messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's more of a journald log than a systemd log, [here's what journalctl says](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) about vacuum size:

> journalctl(1) wrote:
>   `--vacuum-size=`, `--vacuum-time=`
>
> Removes the oldest archived journal files until the disk space they use falls below the specified size (specified with the usual "K", "M", "G" and "T" suffixes), or all archived journal files contain no data older than the specified timespan (specified with the usual "s", "m", "h", "days", "months", "weeks" and "years" suffixes), or no more than the specified number of separate journal files remain. Note that running `--vacuum-size=` has only an indirect effect on the output shown by `--disk-usage`, as the latter includes active journal files, while the vacuuming operation only operates on archived journal files. Similarly, `--vacuum-files=` might not actually reduce the number of journal files to below the specified number, as it will not remove active journal files.
>
> `--vacuum-size=`, --vacuum-time= and --vacuum-files= may be combined in a single invocation to enforce any combination of a size, a time and a number of files limit on the archived journal files.